# Como imprimir apenas a primeira coluna de um dataset com o numpy?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

Como imprimir apenas a primeira coluna de um dataset com o numpy?

Meu código:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("iris.data",delimiter = ",",usecols=(0,1,2,3))
print(data)
```

Meu dataset (parte dele):

```
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.0,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.6,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.4,2.9,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.7,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.0,1.4,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.3,3.0,1.1,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.8,4.0,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.7,4.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.9,1.3,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.5,1.4,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.7,3.8,1.7,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.8,1.5,0.3,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.7,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.7,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
4.6,3.6,1.0,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.3,1.7,0.5,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.4,1.9,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.0,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.4,1.6,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.5,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.2,3.4,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.7,3.2,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.8,3.1,1.6,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.4,3.4,1.5,0.4,Iris-setosa
5.2,4.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.5,4.2,1.4,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.2,1.2,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.5,3.5,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
4.9,3.1,1.5,0.1,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.0,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.1,3.4,1.5,0.2,Iris-setosa
5.0,3.5,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.5,2.3,1.3,0.3,Iris-setosa
4.4,3.2,1.3,0.2,Iris-setosa
```

Gostaria de pegar apenas a primeira coluna do dataset inteiro. Como fazer com o numpy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui resolver fazendo um *slice* do *dataframe*:

data[0:,0:1] -> vai pegar apenas a primeira coluna do dataset inteiro.
O programa fica:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.genfromtxt("iris.data",delimiter = ",",usecols=(0,1,2,3))
#print(data)

print(data[0:,0:1])
```